# vuejs изменение переменной из data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Не пойму почему при вызове console.log(this.imagePath) я получаю UNDEFINED, вместо "Hoho". Соответственно заменить переменную не получается вообще. Как правильно ее заменить?

```
data() {
        return {
            imagePath: 'Hoho',
        };
    },
    methods: {
        selectImage() {
            var lfm = function(options, cb) {
                var route_prefix = (options && options.prefix) ? options.prefix : '/laravel-filemanager';
                window.open(route_prefix + '?type=' + options.type || 'file', 'FileManager', 'width=900,height=600');
                window.SetUrl = cb;
            }
            lfm({type: 'image', prefix: ''}, function(url, path) {
                console.log(this.imagePath, path);
            });
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lfm({type: 'image', prefix: ''}, (url, path) => {
    this.imagePath = path;
});
```

Забавно, но замена function (url, path) на (url, path) => решило проблему... Но я не понимаю почему =)

Comment: Потому что начали писать код без знаний должного уровня. Конкретно в этом случае надо подтянуть знания в области контекста выполнения и погуглить "Что такое this в JavaScript".

Comment: @yarkov_aleksei должный уровень знаний из практики приходит быстрее))

Comment: @PaulWall однако в данном случае вы так и не поняли почему проблема решилась ?

Comment: @zalex ну как я это понял, с => я использовал глобальную область видимости переменных

Comment: Нет, вы использовали стрелочную функцию, в которой this отсылает к объекту в котором вы его вызвали. При использовании function () {}  this имеет другой контекст.   Вот @yarkov_aleksei вам намекал об этом почитать :)

Comment: Так же обратите внимание вот сюда https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html  там говорится когда не стоит использовать во vuejs стрелочные функции.

Comment: @zalex я думал используя function() {} я там внутри создаю своб область видимость переменных

Comment: function может использоваться в разных контекстах и this в той же самой функции может указывать на совершенно разные вещи.   Я погуглил за вас :) https://learn.javascript.ru/object-methods